# How to fix ambiguous redirect when executing a loop reading a text file?

Tags: bash

I getting the error ambiguous redirect when trying the execute a command through a list of files. I have already tested that the command works well when doing the loop file by file.

```
for i in "file1.vcf" "file2.vcf"
do
  grep -e "#" -e "PASS" /home/hpz440/Documents/P/example/input/$i > /home/hpz440/Documents//example/output/$i'_PASS'.vcf
  echo $i
done
```

Now, as I have thousands of file inputs, and I wanted to put the path for all of them in a list.

```
for i in 'cat authomatic_test.txt'
do
  grep -e "#" -e "PASS" /home/hpz440/Documents/P/example/input/$i > /home/hpz440/Documents//example/output/$i'_PASS'.vcf
  echo $i
done
```

But the I get this error:

> bash: /home/hpz440/Documents/example/output/$i'_PASS'.vcf: ambiguous redirect

My list is a txt file like this:

```
hpz440@yasminlima:~/Documents//example/input$ cat authomatic_test.txt 

/home/hpz440/Documents/example/input/file1.vcf
/home/hpz440/Documents/example/input/file2.vcf
```

Could anyone give me a light?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't abuse cats. [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: There are a couple of problems here, but mainly the reason for your error is a typo you have. You wrote `'cat authomatic_test.txt'` while it should have been `$(cat authomatic_test.txt)`. Because of this typo, your `$i` will represent the string `"cat authomatic_test.txt"` and not the expected content. But also read the comment of Karmil Cuk, never use cat and for together.

Comment: Also, you might have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/, this points you to various problems you might have.

Comment: And the preferred way to get a variable value token-pasted into a file-name is to use curly braces round the token name: `$i'_PASS'` ==> `env${i}_PASS`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 'cat authomatic_test.txt'
# i='cat authomatic_test.txt'
... > /home/hpz440/Documents//example/output/$i'_PASS'.vcf
```

The variable `i` has a space in it. Variable expansion with spaces are allowed in the destination of the redirection, but are ambiguous - should the space be part of the filename, or should it split the token into a filename and argument?. Bash prints `ambiguous redirect` error, because it can't parse the destination. After shell expansion it is expanded to:

```
... > /home/hpz440/Documents//example/output/cat authomatic_test.txt'_PASS'.vcf
```

What you want is this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -e "#" -e "PASS" /home/hpz440/Documents/P/example/input/"$i" > /home/hpz440/Documents//example/output/"$i"_PASS.vcf
done < authomatic_test.txt
```

Remember about proper understanding and using [quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).